# Is custom paging of GridView (in ASP.NET, preferably 3.5) possible without using ObjectDataSource?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging

See title.

Using ObjectDataSource is associated in my mind with quick demos that you can see at conferences and in video tutorials (which typically tells me "don't do it this way in production").
Also I always like to have control over what's going on and when it happens. My other problem with ObjectDataSource is that is's declarative.

Looking forward for your help and opinions.

UPDATE:
I'm retrieving only one page of results from the database and the GridView.PageCount is read-only [sic!].

Comment: From what I have found so far is that I would probably have to implement the IDataSource interface, which the ObjectDataSource does for me. I really wish I could be able to set GridView.PageCount property.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to define an PageIndexChanged event handler to perform the actual paging of data from your source before binding to the Data Grid, same idea for sorting but with a SortCommand handler.